# How to return '0' from a dictionary if the key is not found Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a dictionary with classes and the number of pixels of each class in polygons. There are classes that do not occur in all polygons, I would like in those cases return the value '0'. I was analyzing how to do it with the following simple code:

```
var dict = {
  0: 182,
  1: 219,
  2: 443,
  3: 200
};

var dicto = ee.Dictionary(dict)
var selec = ee.Algorithms.If( '3' in dicto.keys() ,dicto.select({selectors:['3']}), 0)
print(selec)
```

However, print gives me '0' instead of the value that it should have. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

`ee.Dictionary.get()` takes two arguments, `key` and `defaultValue`. You want to set `defaultValue` to `0`. From the docs:

> Extracts a named value from a dictionary. If the dictionary does not
> contain the given key, then defaultValue is returned, unless it is
> null.

```
dicto.get('4', 0)
```